# Como usar o atributo onclick em C# Webbrowser?

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet

```
HtmlElementCollection elementButton = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
foreach (HtmlElement elementyButton in elementButton)
{
 if (elementyButton.GetAttribute("onclick") == "ExecutarLance('46097');")
 {
  elementyButton.InvokeMember("click");
  SendKeys.Send("{ENTER}");
 }
}
```

Eu preciso manusear o atributo onclick, mas não retorna nada.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor o que pretende fazer? A pergunta não está clara para mim

Comment: Eu pretendo programar um click automático, mas o click só pode acontecer em um local especifico, o único atributo diferente dos demais é o onclick. Eu consigo por exemplo usar a class, mas o site tem vários botões com a mesma class, se eu fizer pela class o click será em todos os elementos que usam a class, e são muitos, então o click ocorrerá em todos esses elementos, mas eu só quero o click em um elemento específico e o único atributo que diferencia um elemento do outro é o onclick, mas dar getattribute no onclik não retorna nada, gostaria de saber como acessar esse atributo onclick.