# c# WebBrowser Como chamar a função onclick?

Tags: c#, navegador-de-internet

Como chamar a função `onclick` deste `html`:

```
<a  
  href="javascript:;" 
  onclick="ExecutarLance('46368');"
  title="ExecutarLance" 
  class="btn btn-custom3">
    LANCE
</a> == $0
```

Comment: poderia detalhar melhor?

Comment: Gostaria de invocar a função onclick deste html, seria com o invokescript?

Comment: você não pois o código inteiro na sua pergunta poderia melhorar a sua pergunta como você fez?

Comment: Tem o endereço completo do site?

Comment: Tem o código que utilizou para carregar a informação.

Comment: Eu gostaria de fazer um click automatico em um botão de um site. Porém o unico atributo que eu posso utilizar é o onclick, pois no site tem varios botões que utilizam o mesmo href, class e title, mas se eu utilizar qualquer um destes o click será em mais de botão ao mesmo tempo

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/491468/como-usar-o-atributo-onclick-em-c-webbrowser é uma duplicata, só precisa abrir uma.

Answer (score 1):

Pode invocar diretamente o `script` da seguinte forma:

```
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("ExecutarLance", new[] { "46368" });
```

acho que isso possa te dar um caminho para solução do seu problema.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar `elemento.InvokeMember("Click")`, onde `elemento` é o [HtmlElement](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement?view=net-5.0) que você deseja chamar a função onclick.

```
HtmlElementCollection collection = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("a");
foreach(HtmlElement element in collection)
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("title") == "ExecutarLance")
    {
        element.InvokeMember("Click");
        break;
    }   
}
```

Perceba que no código acima identifiquei o elemento pelo atributo **title**, mas você pode alterar para identificá-lo de outra forma mais específica.

**EDIT:** A função correta é `InvokeMember`

Comment: Mas no site que eu quero fazer o click, tem varios botões que utilizam o mesmo title, href e class, se eu utilizar qualquer um destes o click será em mais de um local. O unico atributo diferente é o onclick que o unico do botão que eu quero clicar.

Comment: então altere o código para identificar o elemento pelo atributo `onclick`.

Comment: Eu tentei isso, o código ficaria: element.GetAttribute("onclick") == "ExecutarLance('46368');"

Comment: Mas não funciona

Comment: Realmente, parece que ler o atributo `onclick` de um elemento no C# não funciona. Mas aí já seria outro problema. Veja: https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1074179/Get-javascript-onClick-function-definition-with-we